# Call Controller method of CodeIgniter outside Application directory

Tags: codeigniter

I have one directory "Store" which is outside Application directory of CodeIgniter. Here
I need to call one controller method from "Store" directory.

Is is possible to call controller method from directory which is outside Application Directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it outside the application directory? Why not just move the controller to the normal location?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using `$this->load` (Loader class i.e.), you can't. Even if you directly include like in the following way:

*application/controllers/test.php*

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require('/absolute/path/to/dummy.php');

class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function handle(){
        $d = new Dummy();
        $d->handle();
    }
}
```

---

*dummy.php*

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dummy extends CI_Controller {
    public function handle(){
        // do something here
    }
}
```

**It(including) won't work because you specifically disallowed direct access!** But, if you don't disallow that, then, *your controller code is prone to exploitation*, **and you won't have a problem**.

---

So, one way to do it if the other controller part of another codeigniter project is, using command line.

*dummy.php*

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access 

class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function handle(){
        $d = new Dummy();
        $d->handle();
    }
}
```

*application/controllers/test.php*

```
public function handle(){
    exec("cd /absolute/path/to/dummyproject; php index.php dummy handle;");
}
```

You can further find out how to pass command line arguments too.