# How to call a function in helper from outside codeigniter (ci) - tried the solution from other stackoverflow links but doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a function in application/helpers/ which works fine when accessing from ci.
Now I want to call the same function from outside ci i.e., from core PHP file. But I'm not able to do so.

Below is the approach tried.

Created a test.php outside ci and below is the code:

```
<?php
    $filepath = dirname(__FILE__);
    ob_start();
    require_once($filepath.'/ci/index.php');
    ob_get_clean();
    return $CI;
?>
```

In another core PHP file, test2.php, below is the code:

```
$CI = require_once('test.php');
echo $CI->config->item('base_url');
some_helper_function($param1, $param2);
```

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in <path>/Utf8.php on line 47
```

Folder structure:

```
test.php
test2.php
ci/application/helpers/test_helper.php (contains some_helper_function())
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Controller method of CodeIgniter outside Application directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257538/call-controller-method-of-codeigniter-outside-application-directory)

Comment: where is the code for the function you want to get?  What's the purpose of using `$CI` if you want to use it outside of CI isn't that like an oxymoron or something.

Comment: In test2.php, some_helper_function() is the function which is defined in application/helpers/

Comment: @BilalAhmed I have tried that but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Create a file and put the following code into it.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  if ( ! function_exists('test_function'))
  {
    function test_function()
    {
        //your functionality//
    }   
}
```

Save this to application/helpers/ . save it as "test_helper.php"

The first line exists to make sure the File cant be included and run from outside the Code Igniter.

Then in your controller or Model

```
$this->load->helper('test_helper');
```

You can use any function from that helper page.

Else

your-project-name\application\config\autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('test_helper');
```

So that you can use that helper function in any controller or model. Not to initialize in each and every controller or model like previously said.

Comment: Here you have written the code on how to call helper function in controller/model. My requirement is to call the helper function outside the ci.

Comment: Just include your helper page in which page you want to use that helper page function like given below like include('./application/helpers/test_helper.php'); and use that function in that page.

Comment: $CI = require_once 'CI.php';
  echo $CI->config->item('base_url'); // test CI instance   /*Include like this and try */

Comment: https://codeinphp.github.io/post/codeigniter-tip-accessing-codeigniter-instance-outside/

Comment: My approach is from the above link (https://codeinphp.github.io/post/codeigniter-tip-accessing-codeigniter-instance-outside/). It's not working.